# Angular - TransferState - page is loading twice (flickering)

Tags: angular, api, http, dom, angular-universal

I have a little problem with Angular 5.2.10 `TransferState` module. Currently I'm using Angular Universal (latest version) to make my site SEO friendly. Everything is working fine except one thing... Page is loading first - on server side, then content disappear and load on browser side (screen).

[image: blink]

I've created service for `TransferState` implementation (you can see it below).

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { TransferState, makeStateKey, DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

interface pageData {
    banner: string;
    data: any;
    html: SafeHtml;
    text: string;
    title: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class ServerService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private state: TransferState, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

    getResponse(url): Observable<any> {
        url = makeStateKey<Promise<any>>(url);

        let temp = this.state.hasKey(url);
        if (!temp)
            return this.http.get<any>(url).map(
                (response: any) => {
                    let data = response;
                    this.state.set(url, data);
                    return data;
                }
            ).share();
        else {
            return Observable.of(this.state.get(url, null as Observable<any>));
        }
    }

    async getResponseAsync(url): Promise<any> {
        let temp = await this.state.hasKey(url);
        url = makeStateKey<Promise<any>>(url);

        if (!await temp)
            return this.http.get<any>(url).toPromise().then(
                async (response: any) => {
                    await this.state.set(url, await response);
                    return await response;
                }
            );
        else {
            return await this.state.get(url, null as Promise<any>)
        }
    }
    }
```

I've also tried solution with `TransferHttpCacheModule`, but problem remains.

main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  platformBrowserDynamic()
    .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

app.server.module.ts

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule, ServerTransferStateModule } from "@angular/platform-server";
import { ModuleMapLoaderModule } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'; 


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
    ServerTransferStateModule,
    ModuleMapLoaderModule,
    NoopAnimationsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
})
export class AppServerModule {}
```

app.module.ts

```
// Core
import { BrowserModule, BrowserTransferStateModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes, PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgForageModule, NgForageConfig, NgForageOptions } from "ngforage";
import { NgProgressModule } from '@ngx-progressbar/core';

// Config
import { Config } from './config';


// Compontents
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ContainerComponent } from './components/container/container.component'


import { ContainerModule } from './components/container/container.module'


// Environment
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { NotfoundComponent } from './components/notfound/notfound.component';
import { NotfoundModule } from './components/notfound/notfound.module';



const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: '/pl'
  },

  {
    path: 'pl/home',
    redirectTo: 'pl'
  },
  {
    path: '404',
    component: NotfoundComponent
  },
  {
    path: ':lang',
    component: ContainerComponent
  },
  {
    path: ':lang/:index',
    component: ContainerComponent,
  },
    {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '404'
  }

];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { initialNavigation: 'enabled', preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules }),
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'main-app' }),
    BrowserTransferStateModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NgProgressModule.forRoot(),
    NgForageModule.forRoot(),
    ContainerModule,
    NotfoundModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    Config
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})



export class AppModule{
  constructor(ngfConfig: NgForageConfig) {
    ngfConfig.configure({
      name: 'apiDB',
      driver: [ // defaults to indexedDB -> webSQL -> localStorage -> sessionStorage
        NgForageConfig.DRIVER_INDEXEDDB,
        NgForageConfig.DRIVER_LOCALSTORAGE
      ]
    });
  }
}
```

Example repo you can see [there](https://github.com/patrykp57/angular-sample/) (some components are out of date - most important modules you have above)

Do you know how to fix that issue ? Or it's core bug, and I have to wait for fixes ?

Page blink, after inserting state node in document tree (this one marked below main-app-state )

[image]

**Edit**
It's not Service Worker issue also, I've tried to turn it off and still the same.

Github issue [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23427)